# Loop through list not quite responding as expected

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have some code that is supposed to go through the columns of a dataframe and rename some of them to something else.  Simple loop, but it isn't coming out quite as expected.  Here is what I think is the relevant code:

```
Headers = df.columns.values.tolist()
print(Headers)

for i in range(24):
    df = df.rename(columns = {Headers[i+4]: ('b'+ str(32-i))})
    print(i, Headers[i+4], 'b'+ str(32 - i))

Headers = df.columns.values.tolist()
print(Headers)
```

And here is the output:

```
['Lbl #', 'Value', 'Time', 'Name', 'b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8', 'b9', 'b10', 'b11', 'b12', 'b13', 'b14', 'b15', 'b16', 'b17', 'b18', 'b19', 'b20', 'b21', 'b22', 'b23']
0 b0 b32
1 b1 b31
2 b2 b30
3 b3 b29
4 b4 b28
5 b5 b27
6 b6 b26
7 b7 b25
8 b8 b24
9 b9 b23
10 b10 b22
11 b11 b21
12 b12 b20
13 b13 b19
14 b14 b18
15 b15 b17
16 b16 b16
17 b17 b15
18 b18 b14
19 b19 b13
20 b20 b12
21 b21 b11
22 b22 b10
23 b23 b9
['Lbl #', 'Value', 'Time', 'Name', 'b32', 'b31', 'b30', 'b29', 'b28', 'b27', 'b26', 'b25', 'b24', 'b9', 'b10', 'b11', 'b12', 'b13', 'b14', 'b15', 'b16', 'b15', 'b14', 'b13', 'b12', 'b11', 'b10', 'b9']
```

The goal here is to change the b0:b23 to b32:b9, which will then correspond to the data being recorded.  If you look at the second list of column names, the column rename gives an unexpected result.  Starting at about the Index[13:19], the rename function doesn't appear to do anything?

Thanks

Comment: What are you talking about? Humans will naturally reference? b9:b15 response? Proof read your post and see if it makes sense

Comment: I meant, that the data recorded, is MSB first, so bit 32 will be where bit 0 is in my list, I am trying to make it so as we go through the data, when we talk about bit 24, I am entering 'b24' into the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are renaming some of your columns more than once. As you go through your loop, you will rename `b9` to `b23`, but there is already a column named `b23`! Later in the loop you will rename `b23` to `b9`, but there are two `b23`s, so you will end up with two `b9`s in your final data frame and no `b23`.

What you need to do is rename all your columns at once. Instead of your for-loop, do:

```
coldict = {Headers[i+4]: ('b'+ str(32-i)) for i in range(24)}
df = df.rename(columns = coldict)
```